# Solving differential equation and the inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

I have stuck in a small step were I need to solve for t:

$$ e^{t(\lambda_3-\lambda_1)} \geq 1 \Rightarrow t \geq\frac{1}{\lambda_3 - \lambda_1}$$

I don´t understand how the solution is required.

The problem in hand is a bit bigger, though I think I understand most of it.

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{9D}{l^2}Ax$$ Where A is the matrix:

$$A = \left[ \begin{matrix}
        -2 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & -2 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & -2 \\
        \end{matrix} \right]
$$

Solving this is got :

$$x_1(t) = C_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} + C_2e^{\lambda_2 t} + C_3e^{\lambda_3 t}$$
$$x_2(t) = -\sqrt{2}C_2e^{\lambda_2 t} + \sqrt{2}C_3e^{\lambda_3 t}$$ 
$$x_3(t) = -C_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} + C_2e^{\lambda_2 t} + C_3e^{\lambda_3 t}$$

$$\lambda_1 = \frac{-18D}{l^2}$$
$$\lambda_2 = \frac{-9(2+\sqrt2)D}{l^2}$$
$$\lambda_3 = \frac{9(-2+\sqrt2)D}{l^2}$$

If we think about the $x$´s as proportion of a certain material, how will the material be divided in the "areas"($x_1, x_2,x_3)$ after a long time. How much is "long time".

The last question is were I am stuck at, what is long time. Trying to solve for $t$.

Comment: you did a mistake right in the beginning: $\ln(1)=0$ instead of $\ln(1)=1$,so in fact you need $t(\lambda_3-\lambda_1)\geq0$

Comment: If $\lambda_3 > \lambda_1$, then $t\ge 0$

Comment: what about your initial conditions?

Comment: @user190080 That part is written from the solution manual. There is no initial solution. :/

Comment: but you see the mistake in the second line?

Comment: I can see it, but what I do not understand is  why does  two solution manuals. Not one, two! Show the same  result :/